# No DSL internet if splitter is used

Tags: dsl, adsl-router

If I connect my router directly to the main DSL cable, my internet works just fine. If I connect it to a telephone, it also works. When I try to use a splitter to use both the internet and the telephone, only the telephone works - also tried three different splitters, new cables, the router does not even see a DSL connection.

What could cause this issue?

[Splitter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003807GK6):

[image]

Comment: Please show a picture and give the model number of the 3 different "splitters" you have tried

Comment: This is the last model I tried to use, it is a splitter with built in filter. amazon.com/In-line-DSL-Filter-w-Splitter/dp/B003807GK6

Answer (score 1):

You need to use FILTERS, not splitters. A splitter just splices the line in 2, and the phone interferes with the DSL.  A filter,as the name suggests, prevents this interference by putting a low pass filter on the phone leg.

Comment: This is the last model I tried to use, it is a splitter with built in filter.
https://www.amazon.com/In-line-DSL-Filter-w-Splitter/dp/B003807GK6

Comment: What type of DSL do you have? Im scratching a bit but I do note that is a pretty old model - I wonder how well it fairs with VDSL!

Comment: It's VDSL. The thing is, the internet won't work even if the phone cable is disconnected. If it's plugged into a splitter(filter), it just doesn't work. Strange..

Comment: Not strange at all. The filter's behavior does not change depending on what's connected – it gives you certain frequencies on the 'DSL' output and certain other frequencies on the 'phone' output, and that's all it does. It won't "turn off" like that.